# Can I check contact field conditions from the Map?

Tags: apex

I would like to check the condition for npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c field on Contact(as shown in the comments) before performing contactsToUpdateList operation, how could I make use of F2FAgencyIds Map to check the condition?? Or do i need to iterate over contacts separately?

Any leads for the approach is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
  Map<id, Date> F2FAgencyIds=new Map<Id, Date>();    
    for(CampaignMember cm : newCMList)
          {
             if(cm.ContactId != null)
              { 
                 //Get LatestDate..
                 if(campaignChannel == 'Face to Face (Agency)')                                    
                     F2FAgencyIds.put(cm.ContactId, latestDate); 
              }
          }
        
        if(!F2FAgencyIds.isempty())
                    {                       
                        for(ID key:F2FAgencyIds.keyset()){ 
                       //if(npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c == NULL || npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c <= F2FAgencyIds.get(key))
                             contactsToUpdateList.add(new Contact(Id = key,npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c =F2FAgencyIds.get(key)));
                        }                           
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the code above is iterating through a list of Campaign Members, then if the Campaign Member is linked to a Contact, calculate a date value called LatestDate, then put the Contact ID and LatestDate into a Map. Then all of the Contacts in the keyset are updated with the LatestDate, but only if Contact.npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c is null or less than LatestDate. Please let me know if I've missed anything here!

The problem with how you're designing your code currently is you'll have to add a SOQL query to each for() loop as you iterate the F2FAgencyIDs map which is never a good idea. Instead you'll need to start by creating a bulk query that will pull all of the Contacts located in the F2FAgencyMap so they can be referenced. Note that the query below is filtered by your condition requirements to help prevent governor limits and speed up your code. You could also add the conditions in the for() loop mentioned later.

```
List<Contact> contacts = [
    select id,name,npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c 
    from Contact
    where id in :F2FAgencyIds.keyset()
    and (
        npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c = Null 
        or npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c < :LatestDate
    )
];
```

Once these are retrieved, you'll have to iterate the Contacts retrieved to fill in the LatestDate. The important thing to note is that, since Contacts are filtered (unlike F2FAgencyIDs), you'll want to loop through Contacts rather than the keys in F2FAgencyIDs to prevent searching the Contacts list for someone that don't exist.

```
for (Contact con : contacts){
   con.npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c = F2FAgencyIDs.get(con.id);
}
```

And finally update the Contacts:

```
update contacts;
```

This should get you at least in the ballpark, but let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! The *why* is often as (or more) important than the *how* ("teach a man to fish"). Reading "between the lines" it seems to me that the OP might not realize when you can and cannot access fields in Apex, so I suggest that you edit your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Noted and improved!

Comment: f2FAgencyContactList =[ select Id,npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c 
               from Contact 
                                    where ID In :F2FAgencyIds.keyset()
                                    and (npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c = Null 
               or npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c <= :F2FAgencyIds.Values())
                                   ];
This throws an error
System.TypeException: Illegal empty right operand for operator '<' in query 'SELECT Id,npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c FROM Contact WHERE(ID= :tmpVar1 AND (npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c = NULL OR npct_Last_Face_to_Face__c < :tmpVar2))'.

Comment: Same i tried to run with anonymous window it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: @user102391 Can you paste more of your code for reference? The SOQL query in the error isn't matching the query you've mentioned